# Rotation of objects using wind force

Tags: physics, force-fields, rigidbody

I'm using the wind force to blow some floating objects in the wind. I have the Affect -> Rotation checked, but the objects don't rotate. What am I missing?

[image: Force settings][image: Rigidbody settings]

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Try adding a turbulence field, or turning on apbsorption, or that parallel thing where a parallel surface is less affected.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm up against the same thing right now.

Comment: unfortunately no. I love Blender in theory and often in practice but the learning curve can be extreme.